# NavigationViewController with WebView-containing View Controller

Tags: iphone, memory, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

I have a problem with a navigation controller.

First of all, there is a navigationviewcontroller.

Also, there is A webviewcontroller-containing view controller, meaning that webview controller is loaded inside WEBcontroller.m

I made that when the WEBcontroller is loaded, it automatically loads google.com. The function is in the -viewDidLoad()

First, when the app is launched, navigationview loads WEBcontroller.m, then WEBcontroller loads google.com as intended.

Then, when I click any link in the google.com, navigationview pushes a new view with 
[self.navController pushViewController:newWebController animated:YES];
[newWebController gotoUrl:[request.URL absoluteString]];

It, of course, works. The newly loaded(and alloc) WEBController.m loads gmail.com by calling "gotoUrl" function.

And, I click another links to go "gmail.com/help"

So, 
google.com -> gmail.com -> gmail.com/help

Then, I close the app, and play some games... it makes iPhone free memory.

Launching the app again, the "gmail.com/help" webpage is shown. Then, I click the [Back] button which is at the navigationBar which calls [popViewController].

Then, the navigation controller properly go back to preceding WEBController.m which was showing "gmail.com" page.

BUT!! there is a problem. Because the memory was 'dealloc' by iPhone, the WEBController is loaded AGAIN with "google.com" page, not "gmail.com" page.

I've searched this problem but I couldn't get any.

Really thank you for reading and giving some interests to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused. You are using a UIWebView? If so, why don't you just let it handle the links/navigation? Why are you creating (and pushing) a new UIWebView for every link click? Technically speaking, a view controller needs to be able to handle being freed and restored from memory by IOS. This is done in viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload. But I don't think that's what you want/need here.

Comment: I cant explain with technical terms. Actually, I don't always push new UIWebView but here I explained like that for convenience. I'll explain with another example that if there is a tabcontroller with two tab items. When I click the 1st tab followed by 2nd tab. At that time, both UIViews are loaded. Then, I play some games and iOS will free 1st tab's UIView. when I re-launch the app, I can see the 2nd tab's UIView properly, but when I click the 1st tab again, all the information I wrote(or made change) will be lost. How can I handle it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have state that you need to save, you have to write code to do that. How you do that depends. You haven't given much detail. Maybe the user enters text in a UITextField and you want to save it. You could have some backing store such as SQLLite and NSManagedObjects that you store that field to. Or if you don't need the information to live beyond the life of your running app, store it in an in-memory object you create. But you need to handle the case where your view gets unloaded and reloaded. So maybe a singleton or your app delegate retains a reference to that object.